# Plot specific columns values with another column as category with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot a lines plot of specific columns from a dataset with one line per category, that category being another column.

1) Let's start by generating a fake dataset

```
import pandas

import random

df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 7), columns=list('ABCDEFG'))
df['Z'] = np.random.choice(range(1, 6), df.shape[0])

df
```

(wanted to post picture of output but I don't have any reputation, so let me know how I can remedy to that)

2) My question is I want a plot with an x axis being 1 to 100, my y axis displaying variable  B, C and D values, and one line for each Z variable category (between 1 and 6) with a legend for this.

Thank you very much

**EDIT : I found a solution, but I don't think it's very elegant**

I first transpose my rows as columns

```
df.set_index('Z').T
```

Then I plot using

```
df[['B','C','D']].plot(figsize=(10,5))
```

However I don't think it's an elegant solution? (I'm really new to Python). So if anyone has a nice answer to plot from the original dataframe, I would be glad to see it !

Comment: Your solution looks pretty good to me, I think you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Ok will do, thanks for your advice !

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my edit, here is the solution:

1) First transpose my rows into columns

```
df.set_index('Z').T
```

2) Then plot using

```
df[['B','C','D']].plot(figsize=(10,5))
```